# How to filter out groups empty for 1 column in Tidyverse

Tags: r, filter, tidyverse

```
tibble(
  A = c("A","A","B","B"),
  x = c(NA,NA,NA,1),
  y = c(1,2,3,4),
) %>% group_by(A) -> df
```

desired output:

```
tibble(
  A = c("B","B"),
  x = c(NA,1)
  y = c(3,4),
)
```

I want to find all groups for which all elements of `x` and `x` only are all `NA`, then remove those groups. `"B"` is filtered in because it has at least 1 non `NA` element.

I tried:

```
df %>%
  filter(all(!is.na(x)))
```

but it seems that filters out if it finds at least 1 NA; I need the correct word, which is not `all`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will remove groups of column `A` if all elements of `x` are `NA`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  filter(! all(is.na(x)))

# A tibble: 2 × 3
# Groups:   A [1]
#  A         x     y
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 B        NA     3
#2 B         1     4
```

Note that group `"A"` was removed because both cells in the column `x` are not defined.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `any` with `complete.cases`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  filter(any(complete.cases(x))) %>% 
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  A         x     y
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 B        NA     3
2 B         1     4
```

---

In the `devel` version of `dplyr`, we could use `.by` in `filter` thus we don't need to `group_by/ungroup`

```
df %>%  
  filter(any(complete.cases(x)), .by = 'A')
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  A         x     y
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 B        NA     3
2 B         1     4
```